# How much should be the bleed/trim area for a 1.5 x 1 meters Design

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, bleed

What is the safest bleed area size should I keep for the design of 1.5x1 meters in Photoshop

Comment: Depends on your print method and post processing  equipment. Ask your printer. Anyway technically more is safer so if you can put 1 meter of bleed then you are pretty damn safe, i mean 2 cm might be enough but more is safer. So techically a infinite bleed is safest possible thing, thouygh not in practice.

Comment: Ask the print provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your provider.

Some will just trim the banner on the printed area, some could use an extra inch or 2 to iron it folded back to make it more robust...

Just ask the provider.